# RxAndroidBle Scan Timeout

Tags: rx-java2, rxandroidble

I need help. How to set scan timeout for example 10 seconds when i am using rxandroidble.

```
            scanDisposable = rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(
                new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                        .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                        .build(),
                new ScanFilter.Builder()
                        .setDeviceAddress("B4:99:4C:34:DC:8B")
                        // add custom filters if needed
                        .build()
            )
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doFinally(this::dispose)
                .subscribe(
                    resultsAdapter::addScanResult, 
                    this::onScanFailure
                );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to emit an error (`TimeoutException`) when there is no emission for a specific time then you put a `.timeout(int, TimeUnit)` after the `RxBleClient.scanBleDevices()`.

If you want to simply complete the scan without any error then you put `.take(int, TimeUnit)` in the same place as above.

Comment: this will work when device is not found. But if we want to set timeout even if the device is found then how do we set that? i.e. `SCANNING PERIOD`

Comment: `.take(int, TimeUnit)`